# Do trusting ocelots despawn?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've finally found a jungle in my world, and spotted a couple of ocelots that I would like to bring back to my base. I've gained their trust since I've fed them with raw fish.

However, they're still [ambient, passive mobs](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Mob#Ambient_mobs). Will they despawn after a while? Do I need to name them with a name tag?

Comment: They shouldn't, but I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just spawned a bunch of ocelots, tamed some of them, ran `/say @e`, flew >128 blocks upwards (because mobs that can despawn will instantly despawn when more than 128 blocks away from all players) and ran `/say @e` again. The second time I got much less output, but still some ocelots.

So the answer is: Trusting ocelots do not despawn, others do.